# How to get \paragraph to have the same formatting as \chapter \section \subsection \subsubsection in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm using paragraph as I need some entries to go to a higher depth than subsubsection, however in the table of contents the font for \paragraph is different than for the others (weirdly the font size is bigger for \paragraph), and the page number for \paragraph is both a different font and not in line with the page numbers for the others. How do I fix it so \paragraph is formatted the same as the others?

Comment: the settings are entirely under the control of the document class you are using (unless you are using a package for reformatting tables of contents) so not possible to say in general and you have given no clues, basically just copy `\l@section` to `\l@paragraph` and edit as you wish

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable tex code resulting in your issue, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that has this problem, the commands

```
\renewcommand\cftparafont{<Insert font commands for text in table of contents>}
\renewcommand\cftparapagefont{<Insert font commands for page numbers in table of contents>}
```

e.g.

```
\renewcommand\cftparafont{\footnotesize \sf}
\renewcommand\cftparapagefont{\bfseries\sffamily}
```

Allows you to fix this